# Simple textbox, submit with enter, in AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey, hotkeys

I never write an AutoHotKey script with a GUI, so I'm a little lost about how can I achieve what I want.

I need that after pressing a hotkey opens a empty textbox that let me write anything until I press Enter. That key will close the textbox and somehow save that text in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a couple of minutes of reading autohotkey documentation [Autohotkey GUI](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm) i create what i need

```
#SingleInstance, force
#o::
Gui, Add, Edit, vMyEdit -WantReturn
Gui, Add, Button, Default, OK
Gui, Show
return

Escape::
Gui, Destroy
return

GuiClose:
Gui, Destroy
return

ButtonOK:
Gui, Submit
SendInput <%MyEdit%>{Enter 2}</%MyEdit%>{Up}{Tab}
Gui, Destroy
Return
```

Also one can use an InputBox but i don't find how can subscribe the Escape key to kill the popup window, so i stick with this long but functional script.

Comment: So, have you answered your original question?

Comment: BTW, you don't need to "subscribe the Escape key" for an InputBox. Typing Esc does the same thing as pressing the Cancel button (and kills the popup window).

Comment: @martineau your right, it doesn't work because i have running at the same time this other script, xD...thanks